# How to have an optional dependency enable another optional dependency rust

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am creating a library in rust and I have different features which the user can enable via optional dependencies. I want it so if the dependency `diesel` is enabled than `diesel-derive-enum` should also be enabled.

```
[dependencies]
diesel = {version = "1.4.6", optional = true, features = ["postgres", "chrono"]}
diesel-derive-enum = {version = "1.1.1", optional = true, features = ["postgres"]}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of Rust `1.60.0`, with the [stabilization of namespaced dependencies](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/pull/10269), you can now do this without having to add a differently named feature, using `dep:` features.

```
[dependencies]
diesel = {version = "1.4.6", optional = true, features = ["postgres", "chrono"]}
diesel-derive-enum = {version = "1.1.1", optional = true, features = ["postgres"]}

[features]
diesel = ["dep:diesel", "dep:diesel-derive-enum"]
```

Now you can simply pass `--features diesel` to cargo to enable both the `diesel` and `diesel-derive-enum` optional dependencies.

See the Cargo Book's section on [Optional Features](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/cargo/reference/features.html#optional-dependencies) for more details.

Comment: Very useful answer, better than the accepted one. Keep going :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use cargo `features` to enable multiple optional dependencies.

Here is an example:

```
[dependencies]
cli-color = { version = "0.1.20", optional = true }
clap= { version = "0.2.3", optional = true }

[features]
cli = ["cli-color", "clap"]
```

Also a real world example coming from `tokio`.
https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/blob/master/tokio/Cargo.toml

For more details see official rust docs:
https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html#the-features-section